# Do Security updates require a compile?

Tags: security, patches

I would like to apply the security hotfix for the recently found vulnerabilites: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4426353041293-Security-updates-available-for-Adobe-Commerce-APSB22-12-

Is it sufficient to apply the patch via the patch-command or do I have to do the `di:compile`-dance as well?

In other words: Should I request a downtime for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Adobe tells us to simply refresh the cache

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028367731